# Etymology of "chookas"

Tags: etymology

"Chookas" is an Australian (?) word, used in the theatre to wish people luck, much like "break a leg".

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Break_a_leg#Alternate_terms) points to the [Behind Ballet](http://www.behindballet.com/ask-colin-chookas/) blog, which explains:

> I have been told that the use of ‘chookas’ to wish a performer good luck is uniquely Australian. It seems to have come into use during the early days of J.C. Williamson’s dominance of the theatre scene in Australia. In the early 1900s chicken was regarded as a treat (even in my experience ‘chicken in the basket’ was the most expensive dish on a menu). As most shows paid fees depending on the box-office take, a full house meant that the performers would be able to afford a chicken meal. The cry ‘chook it is’ was shortened to ‘chookas’, and eventually used by performers to wish each other a successful show regardless of the number of people in the auditorium.

That smells of a folk etymology to me. Is there any evidence for this?

Comment: I started to research this, but fell down the rabbit hole of people's last names, Jewish customs, rats, earthen water containers, and a Kenyan tribe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*[The Concise New Partridge Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English](http://books.google.fi/books?id=cCVnlIUTpg4C&pg=PA139&lpg=PA139&dq=chookas&source=bl&ots=cROwNZJVir&sig=f2gsaK5GsncPL7pF2qD57ixPEmY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=KBQ-UKHRIM3O4QTi2oDoBQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=chookas&f=false)* (2007) says:

> **chookas!** used for wishing an actor good luck. Actors are, by tradition, superstitious , and to actually wish an actor 'good luck' in so many words is thought to be tempting fate; this abstract (derivation unknown) or surreal benediction was used by Evan Dustan, an Australian theatrical agent during the 1980s. *AUSTRALIA*, 1984

Comment: This question has now been viewed 10,000 times, but only 3 upvotes on the answer? Share the love!

Answer (score 5):

As per [this post](http://www.theatre.asn.au/green_room_gossip/chookas) from 2006 in an Aussie theatre forum, Joe McCabe provides a similar story:

> I first came across it at the *old firm of JCW’s* way back in a prestroke life.
>
> *There was a poem that went with it, but I can’t remember it now. 
>   The bit I do recollect is the complete term is ‘Tio Tio Tio Chookas’*
>   loosely meaning ‘With hear & sole. May you always play to a full
>   house’
>
> Also the actions which go with the poem, were using your right hand,
>   pat your left heart 3 times with the words ‘tio’ & jump up on
>   ‘Chookas’.
>
> There are still a few old members of the ‘Firm’ & possibly some
>   still on the perch, that played the ‘halls’  back in the 1900’s.
>
> Who may remember the old poem?
>
> But Chookas was derived during the days of the ‘Halls’. At a time when
>   it was considered a delicacy to have a meal of chook & it could
>   cost almost a good weeks pay, unless you were lucky enough to be in
>   digs that had them in the back yard.
>
> At best the ‘Coolgardie safe’ or if the Iceman cometh, was the only way to keep meat generally.
>
> On the halls & indeed with most theatre productions performance
>   fees paid depended on the box office take for the performance, Much the
>   same as little jonny would like to do & virtually come in full
>   circle - so there is nothing new there in the IR laws!
>
> *Apparently the SM or Manager would check the house before the
>   ‘Beginners Ready’ cue & advise if they were to have chook to night
>   or not. Hence the call would go around back stage, something like
>   "chook it is" tonight everyone, which became shortened to chookas after
>   a while.*
>
> Supposedly’ Tio Tio Tio’ was added with the influx of European
>   performers around that ttime, suggested to mean ‘With heart & sole’!
>   *This would also falls in line with the old chook raffles of the time,
>   when the publican or whoever was running it,  would create
>   interest in the raffles by continually calling out various things from
>   chooks to chookas!*

To summarise, the story provided appears to concur with the "Behind Ballet" blog post. Joe McCabe mentions both J.C. Williamson as well as the "chicken tonight" aspects with a note that it might have been popularised by a song that also incorporated "*toi, toi, toi*", a similar phrase which also finds mention in the [WP article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Break_a_leg#Alternate_terms). But, he observes as an afterthought that the call of "*chookas*" might have already been associated with [chook raffles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chook_raffle).

Answer (score 1):

I've just come back from a backstage tour of the Sydney Opera House. We viewed their correspondence / well wishing notes pinned on the backstage notice boards (eg; 'Thanks, guys') all ending in 'Chookas.' The tour guide related this to the (chicken) explanation cited here earlier: That 'chookas' is an old Aussie term meaning, basically, 'Here's to a full house' (so that you can eat chook/chicken tonight).
Chookas,
from Fiona B

Answer (score 0):

I learnt it back in the 80s. Originally pronounced Choogas, it's a derived and typically Aussie abbreviated version of "Cheers and good wishes".

Nothing to do with chicken.

**Edited to add Simon Peppercorn's clarifying details into the answer after Meta Ed and Chappo's observations in comments**

I have indeed been part of Australia's musical theatre scene for almost almost 30 years. This meaning was explained to me by other performers who had been the industry for many years before that

Australians have a strong history of abbreviating words as they are being pronounced., eventually becoming part of the Australian vernacular. Examples include: Arvo – Afternoon; Barbie – Barbecue; Bottle-O – Bottle Shop, basically a place to buy alcohol; Brekky – Breakfast; Ciggy – a Cigarette; Maccas - McDonalds; Straya – Australia; Sunnies – Sunglasses; And so on...

Comment: Can you turn this into an expert answer by adding supporting evidence?

Comment: This answer runs directly counter to the two other answers, which both provide clear references. If you can't cite supporting evidence, at the very least you should explain what knowledge or expertise you have that gives your answer credibility. E.g. did you work in the theatre in Australia in the '80s? Who told you the meaning you've given?

Comment: I have indeed been part of Australia's musical theatre scene for almost almost 30 years. 
This meaning was explained to me by other performers who had been the industry for many years before that.

Comment: Australians have a strong history of abbreviating words as they are being pronounced., eventually becoming part of the Australian vernacular. Examples include:

Arvo – Afternoon;
Barbie – Barbecue;
Bottle-O – Bottle Shop, basically a place to buy alcohol;
Brekky – Breakfast;
Ciggy – a Cigarette;
Maccas - McDonalds;
Straya – Australia;
Sunnies – Sunglasses;

And so on...